# How to call methods in a class of generic type T on variables of the same type but that are not declared Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'd like variable f to be as the same type of the generic parameter F, but I can't declare f in the constructor of the class.

```
  class myClass<F: myInterface>(
     private val v1: String,
     private val v2: String,
  ){
     f.methodOfMyInterface()
  }
```

Comment: Then where do you get the `f` reference from? And where do you want to call `f.methodOfMyInterface()`?

Comment: Well, you can declare it inside the body of the class, but you still need a way to instantiate it: `private val f: F = ???`

Comment: What's the reason you can't declare it in a constructor?

Probably the closest you can get is to make the constructor accept a lambda which will instantiate F, then you can invoke it and assign its result to the field.

Comment: I mean, i'm looking for a way (maybe reflection) to declare f as the type F, but the problem is that F is known only at run time, not in compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply declare `f` as being of type `F`, e.g.:

```
class MyClass<F: MyInterface>(/*…*/) {
   val f: F = /*…*/
}
```

It doesn't matter that `F` isn't known at compile-time: the compiler will ensure it all works out at run-time.

(If you're interested in how it's implemented: in Java and Kotlin, generics like this are implemented by [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which means that the compiled bytecode knows nothing about `F`.  It simply uses the relevant upper bound on the type, which in this case is `MyInterface`.  The compiler makes sure that it's only used in a type-safe way.)

When creating an instance, you'll need to give the compiler a clue as to what type `F` is.  You could do it directly, e.g.:

```
val myClass = MyClass<SomethingImplementingMyInterface(/*…*/)
```

Or you could specify the resulting type:

```
val myClass: MyClass<SomethingImplementingMyInterface> = MyClass(/*…*/)
```

Or one of the parameters could mention that type.  For example, if the class were:

```
class MyClass<F: MyInterface>(val f: F)
```

then the compiler could infer it from that:

```
val myClass = MyClass(SomethingImplementingMyInterface())
```

(Note: I'd be very wary about using reflection.  It's great for tools, plug-ins, and other special cases; but for general application code, it's rarely necessary, as well as being slow and usually not type-safe.  There's usually a better design that avoids it.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully certain that this fulfils your needs, but this is probably as close as you can get:

```
interface Test

class ImplTest : Test

class Data<T : Test>(factory: () -> T) {
  val t: T = factory()
}

inline fun <reified T : Test> data(): Data<Test> {
  return Data { T::class.java.newInstance() }
}
```

Then you can invoke:

```
data<ImplTest>()
```

And this will return you a `Data` object, which will have an instance of `ImplTest` assigned to the `t` field.

Assumptions:

- You're fine with reflection.
- You can assume that whatever `T` is has an empty constructor.